# Why the puncation related to colon closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Spaces around a colon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67394/puntuation-relating-the-use-of-colon#comment129376_67394)

as duplicate of

[Is it ever correct to have a space before a question or exclamation mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark)

My question is about leading and trailing space. In question only leading space was in queston. Why are they duplicates. They are two different symbols.

Comment: Well, it's open again.

Comment: I actually explained my reasoning in comments. The question is answerable by checking Wikipedia. So it can be closed as "general reference" without further comment. Instead, I thought I would do you a favor by closing it as a duplicate of a question that contained the answer (an original one, not just a quote from Wikipedia) and commenting to that extent. You wouldn't listen and instead resolved to ad hominem attacks. A pity. Now it's reopened and one of the answers (and a highly upvoted one at that) *is* just a quote from Wikipedia. Surprise, surprise.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8, let me explain this if I can. Wikipedia is not an authority on English language. I am not required to visit their before posting this. I am assuming there are far more professional ppl here at stack than an article of wikipeida which is general dictionary, not a resource about English.

Comment: Point 2. I had question before closed by within 5 min when the question was getting a lot of activity. The mod quote a sentence from wiki and closed it. My friend that should not be the reason to close it. What happen latter, that particular quote later changed in wikipedia so my question was a genuine question. The fact that you use wikipedia to just close question is really wrong pratice.That is no way general reference for english, it can be for other things. And Yes I search it before I posted this.

Comment: Point 3. Please search this in English.SE `colon rules`, my question appears around 2 or 3 entry. Now it was closed as dup but where does that dup appear anywhere in the search. Because that question was about question mark.

Comment: Lastly I am strongly against the wrong decision by moderators. I think it is not good for the site. BTW this is not intended at you at all, and I mean not at all. To me it was just a wrong decision and not just one but my previous closed question was not a duplicate either. Look at it, its got 6 up-votes, ppl find it useful, if it were closed, it would be buried under the pile and forgotten. Moderators decision matter and influence up and down votes. So I'd say use it responsibly. I hope I am not offending any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why that question was closed as a duplicate. I reopened your question.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the opening.

Answer (score 3):

Although the [Question 4645](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645) asked about terminal punctuation marks (i.e. "!" & "?"), Martha's *answer* to that question indeed talked about colons and commas.  So, the accepted answer to 4645 answered [Question 67934](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67394).  I'm pretty sure that was the impetus for closing the question.

If – aside from "don't put a space before a colon" – there's absolutely nothing else to say about the matter, then closing the question was maybe the right move.  After all, the question has been answered.  But, if people want to discuss exceptions, such as standardized test questions:

`adjective : modifier :: verb : ____________`

then Question 4645 – which doesn't ask about colons – doesn't really offer a good place to do that.  Ergo, maybe it'd be better to leave it open.

(I'm not advocating one side of the debate or the other, I'm just explaining what I suspect people were thinking about the matter.)